# Formula for Mapping three values

Tags: c, algorithm, math, bit-manipulation

Hello there i need a formular for the following mapping and i dont want tables, thats the reason of the bit tag ;)

```
  2 -> 1
  1 -> -1
  0 -> 0
```

or

```
 2 -> -1
 1 -> 1
 0 -> 0
```

Comment: A readable version is `int mapping[] = {0, -1, 1};` and usage `mapping[left_value]`.

Comment: Maybe use a table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `(val>>1)-(val & 1)` you get your first result:

```
0 -> 0
1 -> -1
2 -> 1
```

The alternative result can be got with `(val & 1)-(val>>1)`:

```
0 -> 0
1 -> 1
2 -> -1
```